# Have I used "suspicious" correctly?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Herb: What's that smell?
>
> **Herb looks into the pram, suspicious.**
>
> Herb: Honey, I think Marcus needs to have his diaper changed, so I'm just going to take him.

Have I used "suspicious" correctly here to mean that Herb looks into the pram (where Marcus lies) because he has an idea about where the smell is coming from?

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: _Suspiciously_ (without a comma) would be more usual; but that is OK. The difference is that you are referring to what he is thinking, whereas _suspiciously_ would refer to how he is acting. Probably the actor would do the same thing either way, but not necessarily.

Comment: I personally don't think that's the right word to use. A baby can't/didn't commit a crime. Hence 'suspicious' looks odd here. You can consider using the word __doubtful__ instead.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh You can be suspicious that the gift on the table isn't meant for you. Or that your dog fathered the puppies next door.  Suspicion is NOT limited to crime.

Comment: @RonaldSole Hmm. I see. I almost always relate it something more of a misdeed/crime. Will keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: Will delete my comment/s if you'd like to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather odd for me.  I do see this in some writing styles, and I take it to be a way of trying to represent the internal feelings of Herb, rather than describe the outer appearance of his actions.

It is a shortened version of "Herb looks in the pram. He is suspicious". So "suspicious" is an adjective, not an adverb. It describes Herb, not the action of looking.

It is a hard style to use.  It can be effective but in this short extract it seems a little odd.